# A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for button was encountered:

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, custom-button

I am facing the error

> {faultcode:'sf:INVALID_TYPE', faultstring:'INVALID_TYPE: sObject type
>   'SetupEntityAccess' is not supported.',
>   detail:{InvalidSObjectFault:{exceptionCode:'INVALID_TYPE',
>   exceptionMessage:'sObject type 'SetupEntityAccess' is not supported.',
>   row:'-1', column:'-1', }, }, }

on clicking a custom button

**Java Script code on Button Click**

```
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")}

    var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, Parent.Name, 
          Parent.Profile.Name, Parent.Profile.Id FROM SetupEntityAccess 
          WHERE Parent.Profile.Id = '{!$Profile.Id}' AND SetupEntityId 
          in (SELECT Id FROM ApexPage WHERE Name = 'myPage' AND 
          NamespacePrefix = null)"); 

    if(result.records){ 
        alert('yes :) '); 
    } 
    else{ 
        alert('no :( '); 
    }
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it works for me. What is the profile of the user who gets this error? Maybe he doesn't have the proper permissions to read the SetupEntityAccess object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got answer !!!

That looks to be a permissions issue. The user making the request needs to have the **View Setup and Configuration** permission.